# Find subsets of a string but just which is neighbours

Tags: c#, arrays, string, subset

I am trying to extract subsets but not all of them, just which is a *neighbour*. The simple example below;

**Input :** "123456789"

**Result :**

3.Level Subset: out3 : [123,234,345,456,567,678,789] 
..
5.Level Subset : out5 :[12345,23456,34567,45678,56789]
..
8.Level Subset: out8 :[12345678,23456789]

result = [out1,..,out5,..out8]

If there is a cool solution for this and if it can be string operation it will be good.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding your sample input and output. Perhaps you could express this as what some code might look like to call the method you're imagining and output its results, and then show what that text output would look like?

Comment: Thanks, I edited some, I want to find subsets, but not all of them, just which examples I showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do additional error checks to see if `level` is longer than the length of the string etc.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var results = FindSubsets("123456789", 3);
    Console.Read();
}

public static List<string> FindSubsets(string data, int level)
{
    if (level > data.Length || level < 1)
        return null;

    var results = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - level + 1; i++)
    {
        results.Add(data.Substring(i, level));
    }
    return results;
}
```

---

### Edit:

Added string length check against `level`.

### Edit2:

If you want to find subsets of certain length, you can do something like the following. Create a `List<int>` with all the levels you want to find subsets of, then repeatedly call the function. For example, let's say you want to find subsets for levels 3, 5, and 8. Then:

```
var data = "123456789";
var levels = new List<int>() { 3, 5, 8 };

var results = new List<List<string>>();
foreach(var level in levels)
{
    results.Add(FindSubsets(data, level));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, It is working. I will test some in this after I will make correct solution. :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetSubsets(string input, int length)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");

    if (length <= 0) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Length must be greater than 0.");

    if (length > input.Length) 
        throw new ArgumentException("The desired set length is longer than the string");

    for(int i = 0; i<=input.Length - length;i++)
    {
       yield return input.Substring(i, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done using Regex:

```
string input = "123456789";
int size = 3; // set to whatever
MatchCollection split = Regex.Matches(input, @$"\d{{size}}");
string delimited = string.Join(",", split);
```

Or as an extension method:

```
public static string Delimit(this string s, int size)
{
    MatchCollection split = Regex.Matches(input, @$"\d{{size}}");
    return delimited = string.Join(",", split);
}
```

Comment: I tried but this code is giving this result; [1,456789] . But I want like this [123,234,345,456,567,678,789]

Comment: @mocco yes, you need to use `Regex.Matches` rather than `Regex.Split`. answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I basically just brute forced the answer:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getAllSubets(String input){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();            

        for(int i= input.length(); i>=0; i--){
            int z = i;
            for(int j = 0; j+i<input.length() ;j++){
                z++;
                out.add(input.substring(j, z));
            }  
        }

        list.add(out);

        return list;

    }



    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(MyClass.getAllSubets("123456789"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[123456789, 12345678, 23456789, 1234567, 2345678, 3456789, 123456, 234567, 345678, 456789, 12345, 23456, 34567, 45678, 56789, 1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678, 6789, 123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

This was a fun question to do its easy to get tripped up with the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Finding all Subsets:

```
var Input = "123456789";
var Result = Enumerable
    .Range(1, Input.Length)
    .Select(i => Enumerable
        .Range(0, Input.Length - i + 1)
        .Select(j => Input.Substring(j, i)))
    .ToList();
```

To restrain to only some levels, like 3, 5, or 8, simply filter before performing the work, as is done below:

```
var Levels = new List<int>{ 3, 5, 8 };
var Input = "123456789";
var Result = Enumerable
    .Range(1, Input.Length)
    .Where(i => Levels.Contains(i)) // Filter the levels you need before constructing the subsets.
    .Select(i => Enumerable
        .Range(0, Input.Length - i + 1)
        .Select(j => Input.Substring(j, i)))
    .ToList();
```

Results:

123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789

12345, 
23456, 
34567, 
45678, 
56789

12345678, 
23456789